# Python UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymupdf

I am trying to open a file with PyMuPDF, do some edits, and then return it to the frontend.

Following there is the code

```
@app.post('/return_pdf')
async def return_pdf(uploaded_pdf: UploadFile):
    print("Filetype: ", type(uploaded_pdf)) # <class 'starlette.datastructures.UploadFile'>
    document =  fitz.open(stream=BytesIO(uploaded_pdf.file.read()))
    for page in document:
        for area in page.get_text('blocks'):
            box = fitz.Rect(area[:4])
            if not box.is_empty:
                page.add_rect_annot(box)
    
    return {'file': document.tobytes()}
```

The error I get is the following:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 702: invalid start byte`

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Regarding reading the file, I tried several methods, but apparently `BytesIO(uploaded_pdf.file.read())` was the only one accepted by PyMuPDF.

Regarding returning the file, I tried to return it directly, without converting in bytes, but I got a similar error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 10: invalid continuation byte`

I though about changing the econding and tried to insert it into `fitz.open()` but it was not a param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a PDF file-like response by returning a '**FileResponse**' object from the '**starlette.responses**' module.

```
from starlette.responses import FileResponse

@app.post('/return_pdf')
async def return_pdf(uploaded_pdf: UploadFile):
    document = fitz.open(stream=BytesIO(uploaded_pdf.file.read()), filetype="pdf")
    for page in document:
        for area in page.get_text('blocks'):
            box = fitz.Rect(area[:4])
            if not box.is_empty:
                page.add_rect_annot(box)
    
    output_pdf = BytesIO()
    document.save(out_pdf)
    output_pdf.seek(0)
    
    return FileResponse(out_pdf, filename="edited.pdf")
```

We create a object to hold the pdf which is named '**BiteIO**,The edited pdf is saved in '**document.save()**',Then reset the buffer position using '**output_pdf.seek(0)**' and return as '**textFileResponse(filename)**'.

I hope this might help you.